# How can I add a permenant Samba mount with a GUI?

Tags: samba, gui

I would like to be able to add a permanent Samba mount with a GUI interface rather than editing fstab, similar to how I would use `Map Network Drive` on Windows.

My searches have led to suggestions of `gnome-disk-utility` and `KDE Partition Manager`, however neither appear to have an option to add a Samba mount, only work with local physical drives.

I am currently using Manjaro KDE version, however ideally the solution would be available in any distro and desktop environment.

Answer (score 0):

-Hi Merritt, you can use the "smb4k" that's an KDE Graphical tool to SAMBA just help you mount, unmount, create, share folders etc... It's very simple to use it!

Comment: This tool does indeed have some nice options.. however it doesn't seem to have the ability to modify the fstab, nor load shares on boot the way an fstab entry would.